# Insert JS Scripts in prestashop page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating my first prestashop site. I had a little problem when I tried to put a script in cms page.
I have four scripts I want to put them in four different pages... is this possible ?

Script1 exemple:

```
<script src="https://example.com/venue-menu/javascript/widget-button.js?v1"></script>
<script>
  (function()

{ /* some code here */; }
());
</script>
```

And I want to put this div in the pages

```
<div
id="online-booking-widget-iframe"
data-widget-url="https://example.com/384954/menu/"
></div>
```

Any suggestions plz? 
I'm using prestashop 1.7.6.5

Answer (score 1):

There will be a file [page.tpl](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.6.x/themes/classic/templates/cms/page.tpl) with the below contents.

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='page_title'}
  {$cms.meta_title}
{/block}

{block name='page_content_container'}

<!-- CODE ADDED -->
<script src="https://example.com/venue-menu/javascript/widget-button.js?v1"></script>

<!-- REPLACE BELOW CMS ID 7 -->
{if $cms.id==7} 
<script> (function() 

()); </script> 
{/if}
<!-- end- REPLACE BELOW CMS ID WITH PAGE ID  -->

  <section id="content" class="page-content page-cms page-cms-{$cms.id}">

    {block name='cms_content'}
      {$cms.content nofilter}
    {/block}

    {block name='hook_cms_dispute_information'}
      {hook h='displayCMSDisputeInformation'}
    {/block}

    {block name='hook_cms_print_button'}
      {hook h='displayCMSPrintButton'}
    {/block}

  </section>
{/block}
```

`<!-- CODE ADDED -->`  -> Main jQuery included

```
<!-- REPLACE BELOW CMS ID 7  -->
`{if $cms.id==7}`  => You can place any cms id over here.
```

definitely file page.tpl have to override in the active theme directory.